# hg not able to update via proxy

Tags: linux, mercurial

i am trying to clone a repositiry which is sitting behind a proxy

```
hg --config http_proxy.host=ipaddress:3128 pull "http://servername:8000"

abort: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

on the proxy server(squid) i can see that it does connect

```
1315217673.018    102 ipaddress TCP_MISS/503 1601 GET http://servername:8000/? - DIRECT/- text/html
```

I started the hg server with these commands within the project directory:

```
/usr/local/bin/hg serve
```

listening at http://servername:8000/ (bound to *:8000)

Any idea why mercurial fails???

**fixed using**

```
hg clone ssh://user@servername//var/www/project projectname
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error just now, for me it ended up being I was pointing to the wrong proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

Encountering a similar error message, I resolved it by simply restarting my Apache. My mercurial is configured to start when I start my Apache service. Code:

> apache2ctl restart